# sync data of table between two server using Mysql

Tags: mysql, database, triggers, database-replication

I am having one database 1 on one live server and another database 2 on my developement server. Now what i want to achieve is if on live server in one of the table any operation occurs than it should also be reflected in my same table in database 2 of my development server.

Is it possible via trigger or i need to do any kind of replication...?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### You should use replication for that.

You can re-invent the whole process using triggers and remote tables, but you would be re-inventing replication and it would not be better than the built-in replication.